# Trying to load Redshift samples, Access Denied when COPYing from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm running through the Redshift tutorials on the AWS site, and I can't access their sample data buckets with the COPY command. I know I'm using the right Key and Secret Key, and have even generated new ones to try, without success.

The error from S3 is  S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied. Amazon says this is related to permissions for a bucket, but they don't specify credentials to use for accessing their sample buckets, so I assume they're open to the public?

Anyone got a fix for this or am I misinterpreting the error?

Answer (score 0):

I was misinterpreting the error. The buckets are publicly accessible and you just have to give your IAM user access to the S3 service.